# isub3mon.exe Error Message

Tags: windows-7

I have recently (within 3 days) have had a pop-up on startup show.  it says:

isub3mon.ex - system Error

The program can't start because isub3.mon.dll is missing from your
computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I click "okay" the pop-up disappears.  and nothing happens, until I start the computer up then following time..

since I an computer illiterate, I don't know what to do.  Have not found anything to fix this "problem"

Can you help???

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the [Intel USB 3.0 driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=USB%203.0) and look if this fixes it.